# Only update an object if certain fields are changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out how to only update an object if certain fields have changed. On the most basic level I want to update it if say the startdate or enddate submitted are different but not if the user_id being submitted is different. With that said, if the dates are different and it updates I want the user_id param it be used. I've ssn ways to remove the parameter completely, but that seems like it would result in the user not being updated:

form:

```
 <%= form_for(@enrollment) do |f| %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :enddate %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :enddate %>
 </div>

 <%= f.submit 'Term Plan'%>
 <%= f.submit 'Cancel Plan', name: 'cancel_plan'' %>
```

controller:

```
  def update
    authorize @enrollment
    @enrollment.update_attributes(enrollment_params)
    @enrollment.user=current_user

    if params[:cancel_plan]
      @enrollment.enddate=@enrollment.startdate.yesterday
    end

    if @enrollment.save
      redirect_to @enrollment, notice: 'Enrollment was successfully updated.' 
    else
      render action: 'edit'       
    end
  end
```

So in the above example I would only want to save the @enrollment object if the **enddate** was different then before, not if just the **user** was different.

Any thoughts, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated as always!

Comment: sorry, ques it not clear.. do u want to know if some particular attr has been changed/updated?

Comment: Good point. I added this to above, might still not be expressing my question well: So in the above example I would only want to save the @enrollment object if the **enddate** was different then before, not if just the **user** was different.

Comment: @MechDog can you try to use this code: `@enrollment.enddate_changed? && @enrollment.save` ?

Comment: Thanks @KienThanh. I removed a bunch of other fields to simplify the question. That would work for when there are less fields for sure though. Thanks!

Comment: @MechDog, ok so I will add it to answer, please accept it :)

Comment: I don't think its scalable though @KienThanh. It solves the example because I didn't waste space with lots of different repetitive fields. It would not be a good solution to apply out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code: `@enrollment.enddate_changed? && @enrollment.save` instead of `@enrollment.save`